# how can i acces files on my pc remotely from my android?

Tags: wi-fi, windows, remote-access

i want to get files from my windows vista pc directly to my phone. i dont want remote control like i get from teamviewer. there are people using the computer while i am using my cell phone and i need to acces certain files without bothering them. also i want to gain aces to the entire hdd without any permision. something similar to wifi file explorer but from pc to phone. something like airstream (for some reason it doesnt work on my pc).it doesnt have to be free dont mind to spend a few dollars. and i DONT want a external server to contain all my files like mega or dropbox. Also it would be good to have an opsion to do it offline, or only being conected to the router since i need to moove farely big files too.  any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Use File Expert

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert

[image]

Windows/Samba Sharing you can use all your windows file in your mobile by just connected to your router

Note: no internet required (IP Address Required)